# Unable to run Vega-Lite visualization example through local server

Tags: javascript, vega, vega-lite

I am learning Vega-Lite.

When I try to run a simple bar chart example. Browser console throws an error:

I am running [this example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/getting_started.html#embed)

I am using webstorm IDE; It creates a local server through which I am serving webpage to browser. I have also tested with python http server as well. Results are same.

#### Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
vega-embed@4:1 The input spec uses Vega-Lite v4, but the current version of Vega-Lite is vnot available.  
(anonymous) @ vega-embed@4:1
vega-embed@4:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
    at Object.vega-lite (vega-embed@4:1)
    at vega-embed@4:1
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at vega-embed@4:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ce (vega-embed@4:1)
    at Ke (vega-embed@4:1)
    at et (vega-embed@4:1)
    at barexample.html?_ijt=lq5v9im4hg0eforrhc1pcvqivf:55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade dependencies, not vega-embed@4 for vega-lite@4.0.0-beta.2

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.6.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.0.0-beta.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@5.1.2"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.0.0-beta.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@5"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

updating script source fixed the issue:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@4"></script>
```

**Edit:** This was very quick work-around but not a proper solution. @tmori3y2 has written the proper solution and docs are also updated on vega-lite repository.